# Have a dynamic-width div constantly centered within another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a number of boxes with content in them. The number of boxes per row change based on how wide the browser window is.

How can I make it so that the entire collection of boxes is always centered horizontally on the page?

Here is a reference: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9dP7v/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div class="centered">
    <div class="segment">Content</div>
    <div class="segment">Content</div>
    <div class="segment">Content</div>
    <div class="segment">Content</div>
    <div class="segment">Content</div>
    <div class="segment">Content</div>
    <div class="segment">Content</div>
    <div class="segment">Content</div>
    <div class="segment">Content</div>
    <div class="segment">Content</div>
    <div class="segment">Content</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color:grey;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.centered {
    min-width:620px;
    max-width:1920px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}
.segment {
    float:left;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    margin:5px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

I am open to JavaScript and jQuery solutions but if possible I would prefer to stick to HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.centered {
    min-width:640px;
    max-width:1920px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
.segment {
    display:inline-block;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    margin:5px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9dP7v/5/)

Comment: This seems like the best solution. Thank you. If you'll allow one more question: Is there a way that the whole body of content will stay centered even after the browser width is greater than 1920?

Answer (score 1):

i do this

1 -

> .centered {    display:block;    text-align:center; }

2 -

.segment

remove float

add display:inline-block

have fun

Answer (score 1):

it is hard for only HTML/CSS to resolve your issue perfectly. A very simple JS solution is proposed here.

```
<body>
    <div class="centered">
        <span id="segmentList">
            <div class="segment">Content</div>
            <div class="segment">Content</div>
            <div class="segment">Content</div>
            <div class="segment">Content</div>
            <div class="segment">Content</div>
            <div class="segment">Content</div>
            <div class="segment">Content</div>
            <div class="segment">Content</div>
            <div class="segment">Content</div>
            <div class="segment">Content</div>
            <div class="segment">Content</div>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('div.centered').width($('#segmentList').width());
<script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chennanfei/SSv45/2/)

Answer (score -1):

By setting a different width to the container depending on the width:

http://jsfiddle.net/y6JpY/

```
@media screen { .centered { width: 620px } }
@media screen and (min-width: 930px) { .centered { width: 930px } }
@media screen and (min-width: 1240px) { .centered { width: 1240px } }
@media screen and (min-width: 1550px) { .centered { width: 1550px } }
@media screen and (min-width: 1860px) { .centered { width: 1860px } }
```

The numbers are multiples of 310 (300 + 5 pixels margin each side)

This way also the orphaned tiles in the end don't get centered.